# Voltage measurement using the following circuit

Tags: voltage, power-electronics, mains, multimeter, voltmeter

I was given the following circuit for a mains-voltage measurement system. The oscilloscope in the schematic is meant to analyze a low voltage representation of the mains voltage supply.

After simulating the circuit I have noticed that it produces a 5V (peak to peak) sine-wave for the oscilloscope to analyze.

I am a beginner in the field and though I have a basic idea about how each block in the circuit works, I am not too confident about how it all comes together.. Could somebody give me a brief idea about how this circuit works. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: @jonk Yes it measures 12Vrms on the secondary of the transformer. And I am measuring the the peak-to-peak voltage between the bottom node of R3 and ground. (The way the oscilloscope is connected in the picture)

Comment: @Jonk. there is only one connection between sides. (Ignoring the scope impedance) The connection between simply sets a reference level. There is no current passing down that wire.

Comment: @Trevor Thanks. I interpreted the connection at the scope as tying the wires. My mistake! I'll remove my comments, as they aren't appropriate anymore. Appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

240:12V transformer converts the 240Vrms to 12Vrms.

The 3.3K with 12+4.7K is a voltage divider on that which generates ~1.72Vrms across R3.

That's ~+-2.435V peak.

The battery circuit on the right provides a 2.5V reference level which is attached at the top of R3 to fix a reference point.

Note: Since there is only one connection between the left side and right side, ignoring the scope impedance, that connection simply acts are a reference point. There is no current flowing across that wire.

The scope from the other side of R3 to ground will then show a ~5v peak to peak sinusoidal waveform offset to 2.5V centre.

*(Of course, in reality, the scope impedance DOES have an effect and does close a current path connection between left and right. That changes everything a little and Heisenberg pops his head around the corner.)*

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation. Could you please elaborate on how the circuit on the right provides a 2.5V reference that adds a 2.5V positive offset on the 5Vpp signal?

Comment: @John918 see my update. The wire between left and right simply "fixes" the top of R1 at 2.5V relative to the ground point. Remember ground is a relative term which can be thought of as... measured from here.

Comment: @John918 CONTINUED: If the right circuit was simply a connection to ground, the 5Vpk-to-pk would be biased at ground.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry about misunderstanding your schematic. I wasn't familiar with the program you are using and failed to notice the obvious. My mistake.

Trevor is telling you the right words, but I think some pictures might help out. I hope you are familiar with Thevenin, though. Because without it, it may be a little harder to grasp as quickly.

Let's first just break the connection between the two sides: DC and AC. This will let us figure out our starting position before re-making that connection. I've placed the AC portion on the left and the DC portion on the right side. The top panel pair represents your circuit with the wire disconnected and with all the values shown. The bottom panel shows things after Thevenin is applied:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fW9a7q.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

With that in hand, you can now connect things in either of the following ways. I've used a black arrow to indicate a wire connection you can try making and I've used a blue arrow to indicate where you'd take your measurement. Either way, you can get the desired result.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTRSR8.png)</sup>

The bottom panel above shows you your circuit's case. Does this help?

Comment: I like your schematic better but I calculate Vac (equiv ) 1.721739130434782608695652173913 before connection  just kidding about sigfigs ;)  -1% for calc error ;)

Comment: @jonk Thanks a lot for the analysis and the diagrams. This is really helpful.

Comment: Sure.. make my answer look dull and boring LOL. Good work :)

Comment: @Trevor Sorry. I just kept waiting for you to create a visual and finally decided that I cared enough that I'd take on the responsibility to add some graphics, myself. Some people learn better with a combination of a picture and words.

Comment: @jonk Ha, it's all good. The more info/answers the better. :) I was thinking about it, but you did a better job than I was thinking anyway. I usually wait a while these days. Found myself taking half a hour to make them pretty only to find someone else just did the same thing a little too often...

Comment: @jonk it would be nice if SO had a collaboration mode.

Comment: @Trevor Yes. But what I'd really like to see is a process that first categorizes and isolates subject matter that has persistent value and then initiates processes to compile, validate, and elaborate on all the volunteer work on those durable topics in order to help create what amounts to a growing wiki of sorts or some kind of massive collaborative, and self-correcting over time, work product. That could supplement/complement textbooks, etc., and provide a free resource to anyone.

Comment: @jonk, yes indeed. That would be great.

Comment: @Trevor One of the things that is really important is the ability to see something not just one way. But in perhaps a dozen different ways. And I don't mean a dozen slightly different ways. I mean a dozen very distinctly different approaches to the *same problem.* The physicists I've worked with who are the best (in my opinion) can see a problem from MANY equivalent perspectives as well as a few that provide yet deeper insights. The deeper views can be used to derive the shallower ones, but also provide insights into novel approaches that cannot be seen with the shallower perspectives.

Comment: @Trevor We volunteers each have unique perspectives. By combining them into a larger gestalt we could achieve a multi-perspective that is the equivalent of a genius-level result.

Comment: @jonk Indeed, hence my statement, the more info/answers the better. Although I see some answers that appear to be just plain wrong.. but that's another matter.

Comment: @Trevor Well, that's the vetting process. Over time, that self-corrects and also improves. Even the best of us are mostly wrong about the world. We shouldn't read from our betters for their conclusions. We should read from them because of how they ***think*** *about the world*. So it's not the conclusions, it's the manner of thinking that is important to learn from.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Now you can compute the connected result.

Comment: AS usual, we represent voltage sources as Req=0 even though in reality they all have Req that affects load regulation. Have a great career.